# Unexpected Python Printing Unicode Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-string

```
print("✨  ✨")
```

The above code prints

```
✨ �✨✨
```

I could not understand the reason for the occurrence of � and the extra ✨.
Someone, please explain why this happens and how I can get ✨  ✨ as the output. Thanks!

Enviroments:

> ```
> Windows 10 ver. 1909 
> Python 3.8.3 
> MSVSC 1.47.3
> ```

Comment: Works fine for me (Python 3.6.9, Linux)

Comment: I think its totally depend upon the cli i tried it with cmd i got some square with question marks when i tried with the VScode it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to my machine. As a workaround use the `chr()` of the icons instead of copy-pasting them